# Apply a range object to different worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of sheets that are very similar in format; tables with identical headers and lots of fluff all around them.

I want to write code that can alter certain cells in the tables across each sheet in the same way. These tables can change, so the range of interest may be different every time I run this routine. Something like this:

```
Sub Testing()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim WantedRange As Range

'This range could be anything.
Set WantedRange = Cells(5, 5)

For Each WS In Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    'Do stuff with WS.WantedRange
    Debug.Print WS.WantedRange
Next WS

End Sub
```

Problem is, `Debug.Print WS.WantedRange` throws a `Compile error: method or data member not found.` 
Why is this? `WantedRange` wasn't assigned a parent worksheet, so it should be nothing more than a range, which is a property supported by a worksheet object.

Everything works if the line is replaced with `Debug.Print WS.Range(WantedRange.Address)`. My problem with this is that it defeats the purpose of using another variable to store the range for easy readability and efficiency. I might as well store integers representing the column and row indices and write `WS.Cells(WantedRowIndex, WantedColumnIndex)` instead.

Is there a better way?

### Edit 1:

Thanks to Scott Cramer, a range is always initialized with a worksheet even if not specified. So is there a way to make a range-like object without an initialized worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the range object is initialized it is initialized with a sheet. This sheet in your instance is the active sheet.

Therefore by adding WS. in front is like saying:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(5,5)
```

This will throw an error every time.

```
WS.Range(WantedRange.Address)
```

is the proper when using a range object.

You could use a string instead:

```
WantedRange = Cells(5, 5).Address
```

or simply

```
WantedRange = "E5"
```

then use

```
WS.Range(WantedRange)
```

IF you had many ranges to which you will be doing the same thing then create an array of strings then loop through them:

```
Dim StrArr() as String, i&
StrArr = Array("E5","B16","A1:A10")
For i = lBound(StrArr) to uBound(StrArr)
    'Do Stuff with WS.Range(StrArr(i))
Next i
```

Comment: Makes sense, but there's gotta be a way to handle this without resorting to a "hard" data type like a string, such that `Range(WantedRange)` needs to be written every time. Is creating a new class with all the properties and methods of a range but no internally specified worksheet doable?

Comment: to me that would be more work than simply using `WS.Range(WantedRange.Address) ` @BillyMatsumoto